# How I can run Zeitgeist with KDE

Tags: kde, zeitgeist

I can't integrate Zeitgeist with KDE, when I use GNOME, Zeitgeist works correct and logs everything what I'm doing.

Is it a problem that I'm using both graphical environments ?
(I'm going to remove gnome)

Maybe when I install KRONO, then all will be works fine ? - > How to install it ?

Answer (score 4):

What KDE version do you have ? The integration may work with the latest of the KDE (KDE 4.8)

The KDE is having the Nepomuk. Trueg is blogging of the integration between the KDE Activity Manager, Nepomuk, and Zeitgeist : http://trueg.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/randa-and-ontologies-and-whatnot/

[image]

A bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtzeitgeist/+bug/914923:

> Bug Description
>
> qtzeitgeist is requested by Phonon and kde-runtime to add zeitgeist
>   integration
>
> It is a wrapper library around the Zeitgeist DBus API for Qt
>
> It conforms to everything needed in UbuntuMainInclusionRequirements as
>   far as I can see.

Package:libqzeitgeist0

```
... 
Source: qtzeitgeist 
... 
Description: wrapper library around the Zeitgeist DBus API for Qt
 Zeitgeist is a service which logs the user's activities and notifications,
 anywhere from files opened to websites visited and conversations, and makes
 this information readily available for other applications to use. It is also
 able to establish relationships between items based on similarity and usage
 patterns.
 .
 libQZeitgeist is a wrapper library around the Zeitgeist DBus API for Qt.
Homepage: http://zeitgeist-project.com/
```